# how can I use Google Cloud Messaging working with database?

Tags: notifications

I'm working on my app "events app", and I want to show every new event via a notification to every user that has the app.

What I mean is how to send a new notification depending on the event updated in database?

or the sending process of the notification should be manually !!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I will suggest you that when you are updating or inserting new values in your database either MongoDB,Redis,hBase, SQL or any, send a notification message to all app users using your Pub/Sub mechanism or whatever technique you are using to notify a user and after that made corresponding changes in database.
For sending notification messages, you can use MQTT protocol with netty.
Resources:
1. MQTT protocol (version 3.1) :
[MQTT Overview](http://mqtt.org/documentation)
[More on MQTT](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html)

1. Netty (Java) :
   [Netty Overview](http://netty.io/)
   [A good post about Netty](http://ayedo.github.io/netty/2013/06/19/what-is-netty.html)